# How to customize the /CommentTok Latex command (or its presettings) to change the color of comments inside the markdown blocks?

Tags: latex, markdown

Markdown blocks look using the same color schemes.
The comments have the same style with `bash`, `java` or `sql` blocks. It's convenient.

````
>  ```bash
>  # Importe la bande n°4 de l'image satellite en WGS84, puisque la photo est sur la sphère de la terre, UTM 31 (proche Greenwitch)
>  # datée du 15/02/2017.
>  raster2pgsql -I -C -s 32631 -t 50x50 T31TCJ_20170215T105121_B04.jp2 quinze022017_b4 | psql -U postgres -d webmapping -h localhost -p 5432
>   
>  # Modifier B04 en B08 (et b4 en b8) pour importer la bande n°8 également.
>  ```
````

[image]
*I'm generating a .pdf from this markdown file*

But the markdown presetting of colors make my two-sided documents prints not readable enough.
I would like to change the color these comments.

When I do an intermediate dump to a `.tex` file, I can see that the comments are under a `\CommentTok` *Latex* command:

```tex
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\CommentTok{\# Importe la bande n°4 de l\textquotesingle{}image satellite en WGS84, puisque la photo est sur la sphère de la terre, UTM 31 (proche Greenwitch)}
\CommentTok{\# datée du 15/02/2017.}
\ExtensionTok{raster2pgsql} \AttributeTok{{-}I} \AttributeTok{{-}C} \AttributeTok{{-}s}\NormalTok{ 32631 }\AttributeTok{{-}t}\NormalTok{ 50x50 T31TCJ\_20170215T105121\_B04.jp2 quinze022017\_b4 }\KeywordTok{|} \ExtensionTok{psql} \AttributeTok{{-}U}\NormalTok{ postgres }\AttributeTok{{-}d}\NormalTok{ webmapping }\AttributeTok{{-}h}\NormalTok{ localhost }\AttributeTok{{-}p}\NormalTok{ 5432}
 
\CommentTok{\# Modifier B04 en B08 (et b4 en b8) pour importer la bande n°8 également.}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}
\end{quote}

\endgroup
```

That's good. I only have to target `\CommentTok` to customize it a bit.

But how can I do that ?
If for example, I wish this `\CommentTok` to use a `\definecolor{myComments}{RGB}{0,0,113}` color?